# regexec() fails to match pattern

Tags: c, regex, posix

I am trying to match strings like 'sdb-iof-pool    1008.56M   884K' using this regular expression: `^(.*)([\s]+)([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)([K|M|G|T|P]{1})([\s]+)([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)([K|M|G|T|P]{1})(.*)$`

My c code is the following:

```
int reti;
regex_t regex;
size_t maxGroups = 8;
regmatch_t groupArray[maxGroups];
const char * pattern = "^(.*)([\\s]+)([-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+)([K|M|G|T|P]{1})([\\s]+)([-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+)([K|M|G|T|P]{1})(.*)$";
reti = regcomp(&regex, pattern, REG_EXTENDED);
if (reti) {
    regerror(reti, &regex, log_buffer, IOF_MAX_MSG);
    snprintf(error, IOF_MAX_MSG, "%s: Failed to compile regex '%s': (%d) '%s'", __FUNCTION__, pattern, reti, log_buffer);
    return FAIL;
}
reti = regexec(&regex, cmd_output, maxGroups, groupArray, 0);
if (reti == REG_NOMATCH) {
    regerror(reti, &regex, log_buffer, IOF_MAX_MSG);
    regfree(&regex);
    snprintf(error, IOF_MAX_MSG, "Failed to match regex '%s' on '%s': %s", pattern, cmd_output, log_buffer);
    return FAIL;
}
regfree(&regex);
```

Even though tools like [this](http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/) seem to confirm that the regular expression works fine, my program returns:
"Failed to match regex '^(.*)([\s]+)([-+]?[0-9]*.?[0-9]+)([K|M|G|T|P]{1})([\s]+)([-+]?[0-9]*.?[0-9]+)([K|M|G|T|P]{1})(.*)$' on 'sdb-iof-pool  1008.56M    884K': No match"

Comment: The tool is for PCRE/JS regex flavors.

Comment: A few simplifications: `^(.*)(\s+)([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)([KMGTP])(\s+)([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)([KMGTP])(.*)$`

Comment: Well, @Thomas' regex works fine - https://ideone.com/DhIXHH

Comment: @Wiktor: This tool seems to also confirm that the expression works: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/golang/index.html

Comment: Don't try it with a tool, try it with your code ;)

Comment: @Thomas: Your simplified version doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: ***That's** what I wanted to read. Any info on that?

Comment: @tryfonaration: Because it must be declared as `"^(.*)(\\s+)([-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+)([KMGTP])(\\s+)([-+]?[0-9]*\\.‌​?[0-9]+)([KMGTP])(.*‌​)$"` - and remove any invisible trash symbols after copying from the SO comments.

Comment: Nope, this time I get: Failed to match regex '^(.*)(\s+)([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)([KMGTP])(\s+)([-+]?[0-9]*\.<U+200C><U+200B>?[0-9]+)([KMGTP])(.*<U+200C><U+200B>)$' on 'sdc-iof-pool      1008M   844K': No match
It's a mystery. By the way I haven't been able to make the suggested simplified pattern work on any online tool.

Comment: Print the regex source from the regex object if you can. Also, use `(?s)^.(.+).$` as the pattern, then print out capture 1. Also, the _alternations_ in your character classes are literal bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trials and errors using the utility "grep" with the option "-E" for extended regular expression and by reading the manual of the utility I suspected that the character class [\s] was the culprit. The character class [\s] is not recognized by POSIX syntax. [:space:] must be used instead.

Comment: How did you find that out? And what does `space` match?